# How to conditionally execute server-side logic in SvelteKit based on user action

Tags: server-side-rendering, sveltekit

I am developing a web application using SvelteKit and I have encountered a situation where I need the server-side load function to behave differently based on whether the page is being loaded normally or if a user has clicked an "Update" button.

Here’s the current flow of actions:

**Page Load :** When a user visits the page, the load function fetches necessary data from an API and displays it on the page.

**User Action - Update :** When the user clicks the "Update" button, I use SvelteKit’s `invalidateAll` function on the client side to trigger a re-run of the load function. At this point, I want to send an additional API request to update the data and reflect the results on the page.
What I am aiming for is to only send the additional API request and update the data when the "Update" button is clicked, while keeping the standard data fetching logic for normal page loads.

How can I distinguish in the server-side load function whether it has been executed due to a user clicking the "Update" button or due to a regular page load? What kind of signal or indicator can I send from the client side to achieve this?

I am looking for advice on SvelteKit functionalities, patterns, or best practices that could help resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Here's my server-side code

```
import { fetchAssignmentStat, fetchStatistics, fetchUserStat, isFailure } from '$lib/api';
import type LoadInput from '$lib/types/loadInput';
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export async function load({ cookies, url, params }: LoadInput) {
    const projectId = params.project_id;
    const accessToken = cookies.get('accessToken') as string;

    let assignmentStatResult;
    let userStatResult;

    // check if updateButton clicked

    // if clicked true, send update api request and set response data to assignmentStatResult and userStatResult

    // just load api requset
    assignmentStatResult = await fetchAssignmentStat(projectId, accessToken);
    userStatResult = await fetchUserStat(projectId, accessToken);

    if (isFailure(assignmentStatResult)) {
        console.log(assignmentStatResult.data.type);
        throw error(404, {
            message: assignmentStatResult.data.type,
            code: 'NOT_FOUND'
        });
    }

    if (isFailure(userStatResult)) {
        console.log(userStatResult.data.type);
        throw error(404, {
            message: userStatResult.data.type,
            code: 'NOT_FOUND'
        });
    }

    return {
        assignmentStat: assignmentStatResult.data,
        userStat: userStatResult.data
    };
}
```